# calculating limits with sine and cosine involved

Tags: limits

what is the limit of sinxcos2x/x^2+3x as x approaches to zero.
I don't know what to do am completely confused please help me to try it.

Comment: Try this way: what is the limit of $$\underbrace{\frac{\sin x}{x}}_{\to 1}\cdot\underbrace{\frac{\cos(2x)}{x+3}}_{\to 1/3}$$ as $x\to 0$?

Answer (score 0):

Using L'hopital's rule: $$\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{\sin x\cos 2x}{x^2+3x}=\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{\cos x \cos 2x - 2\sin x\sin 2x}{2x+3}=\frac{1}{3}$$

Answer (score 0):

$\lim_{x \rightarrow 0} \frac{ \sin(x)}{x  } \lim_{x \rightarrow 0} \frac{\cos(2x)}{x+3}=....$

Comment: maybe helpful to remind why/when you are able to split the limit up into a product of two limits

Comment: when each limit exists

Comment: I just meant, along the lines of catching a fish, that perhaps that is exactly the part that OP needed to be made explicit.  To my mind this is just an exercise in factoring limits and less likely L'hospital's if you didn't remember the behavior of $sin(x)/x$.  So the emphasis is on looking for a way to split the limit up, and there's essentially one reasonable way to attempt that...